# Air sealing of attic floor of house build in the 50s

Tags: leak, attic

We had the old insulation removed from the attic. The house is in Quebec, and was built in the 50s.

Before putting new insulation, I want to air seal the attic. Two contractors suggested spraying 2" of foam everywhere on the deck, to act as a air/vapour barrier. At first it sounded like a great idea, so I started the process of cleaning up/updating all the electrical wiring that is going through the attic, knowing that after the foam is sprayed, touching to the wiring will be a nightmare.

But I'm now having second though about spraying foam everywhere, as it will make it impossible to inspect the deck and joists for damage, in the case of roof leak for example. It would also make any rework more complicated or impossible. What would be the pros and cons of fully sprayed foam vs sprayed on gaps and cracks only vs plastic vapour barrier from the attic side. Am I missing something that should be considered? See picture below for reference.

[image]

EDIT: The plank deck is not exposed on the ceiling side, as it is covered by finished drywall.

Comment: "would it be better" is asking for opinions which is explicitly [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Asking about Pros/Cons is perfectly acceptable, so an [edit] to ask that would be appropriate.

Comment: Also, the foam doesn't make it impossible, you just need to remove the foam, inspect, then respray. Not impossible, just more time consuming.

Comment: Are you trying to seal the attic or the _ceiling_ of the room below? Your title seems misleading.

Comment: Spray foam will seal the whole ceiling. Future work can be fixed using small can of foams to seal things back up (i.e. 'great stuff')

Comment: Would you like to still be able to use the attic as storage space, or not?

Answer (score 0):

Usually air sealing means sealing the penetrations and edges, not blanketing the whole surface (which is the job of the insulation that goes in after air sealing). You might want to get quotes from another technician or two and see if they recommend a different approach.

Remember to check whether your utility companies and/or government offer programs that will help pay for efficiency improvements. I had my foundation air-sealed with spray foam, (debatably necessary) insulation added to the basement ceiling. Door seals improved, tips on cheap ways to improve window seals, attic air-sealed and several feet of insulation blown into the attic (since I don't plan to use the attic for storage) at a cost of about $900 total after discounts and rebates. Admittedly this was around 2009 and prices have gone up since then, but it was still a massive discount.

Comment: Both contractor quotes included spray foam to act as air and vapour barrier, then about 24" of blown cellulose to reach R-41 to R-60 depending on which. And to your second point, yes I'm planning on using such program as they are quite advantageous.

Comment: Ok, that almost certainly means the approach I suggested. Which won't hurt anything very deep in foam. If something does get buried that you need to access, you rip it away and apply more afterwards. Probably not an issue.